# Label or annotation with subscript and variable source

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an R routine which creates a number of plots from a large set of data. Each plot is labeled with a titles describing the details of the set of points plotted. Unfortunately, I have not been able to use subscripts in the text if I am using paste to combine a complex label. The result is ugly. This is a simplified version of the code using data from R. The title shows the technique I am currently using, without subscripts. The attempt at an improved version is placed either on the x axis or on the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)
x1 = 1
x2 = 2
list <- c(1:4)
tle <- paste("VGM = ", as.character(list[1]),
         "V, VDM = ", as.character(list[2]),
         "V, VGF = ", as.character(list[3]),
         "V, VDF = ", as.character(list[4]),
         "V", sep="")
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
  labs(title=tle) +
  geom_point()
p
p + xlab(expression(V[DM]))  #works fine
p + xlab(expression(paste(V[DM], "= 3"))) # works fine

# now we would like to use a variable to provide the number

p + xlab(expression(paste(V[DM], "=", x1))) # Just displays "x1", not value of x1
p + xlab(expression(paste(V[DM], "=", 
                      as.character(x1)))) # NO
p + xlab(expression(paste(V[DM], "=", 
                      as.character(as.number(x1))))) # NO
my.xlab1 <- bquote(V[DM] == .(x1)) 
p + xlab(my.xlab1) # We can see the success here

# A single variable at the end of the expression works
# What if you wanted to display two variables?

my.xlab2 <- bquote(V[GM] == .(x2))
my.xlab3 <- paste(my.xlab1, my.xlab2) 
p + xlab(my.xlab3) # doesn't work

# Apparently the expressions cannot be pasted together. Try another approach.
# Place the two expressions separately on the plot. They no longer need to be
# pasted together. It would look better, anyway. Would it work?

p + annotate("text", x=4, y=30, label="Annotate_text", parse=TRUE) 
# This is the idea
# p + annotate("text", x=4, y=30, label=bquote(V[DM] == .(x1)), parse=TRUE) 
# This is a disaster
# RStudio stops the process with a question mark placed on the console. Appears that
# more input is being requested?
p + geom_text(x=4, y=30, label="Geom_text") # works
p + geom_text(x=4, y=30, label=my.xlab1) # does not accept variables.
```

I have included comments which describe the problems raised by each attempt. Ideally, the information should probably be placed as an annotation on the plot rather than as a title, but I cannot find a way to do this. Using a subscript turns a character into an expression, and it seems that there is a long list of functions which handle characters but not expressions.

Comment: Nice work putting together a reproducible example and showing all your work. I wish all questions were this well written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to "paste" two expressions together, you need to have some "operator" join them. There really isn't a paste method for expressions, but there are ways to put them together. First, obviously you could use one `bquote()` to put both variables together. Either

```
my.xlab3 <- bquote(V[DM] == .(x1)~ V[GM] == .(x2))
my.xlab3 <- bquote(list(V[DM] == .(x1), V[GM] == .(x2)))
```

would work. The first puts a space between them, the second puts a comma between them. But if you want to build them separately, you can combine them with another round of `bquote`. So the equivalent building method for the two above expressions is

```
my.xlab3 <- bquote(.(my.xlab1) ~ .(my.xlab2))
my.xlab3 <- bquote(list(.(my.xlab1), .(my.xlab2)))
```

All of those should work to set your `xlab()` value.

Now, if you also want to get annotate to work, you can "un-parse" your expression and then have R "re-parse" it for you and you should be all set. Observe

```
p + annotate("text", x=4, y=30, label=deparse(my.xlab3), parse=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you! It works very well. I have also tried the parse and deparse elements in a call to geom_text, and that worked! Wow. Thank you again.

Comment: I've updated with a slightly more elegant use of `bquote` again to bring two or more elements together.